# forall insert taking more time to insert

Tags: sql, insert

forall insert taking more time to insert am having only 4000 rows in application payment table.. is there any way to optimize my code

```
DECLARE
   TYPE PAY_TAB_REC IS RECORD (
      PAYMENT_ID           NUMBER,
      PAYMENT_TYPE_ID      NUMBER,
      AMOUNT               NUMBER,
      PAYMENT_DATE         DATE,
      CREATED_DATE         DATE,
      CREATED_BY           NUMBER,
      PAYMENT_RECEIPT_NO   VARCHAR2 (20),
      MODIFIED_BY          NUMBER,
      MODIFIED_DATE        DATE,
      PAYEE_ID             NUMBER (10),
      PAYER_ID             NUMBER (10),
      IS_URGENT            NUMBER (1)    DEFAULT 0,
      APP_ID               NUMBER
   );

   TYPE PAY_TAB_TYPE IS TABLE OF PAY_TAB_REC
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   PAY_TAB   PAY_TAB_TYPE;

   CURSOR C_APP
   IS
      SELECT SEQ_PAYMENT.NEXTVAL PAYMENT_ID, PAYMENT_TYPE_ID, AMOUNT,
             PAYMENT_DATE, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, PAYMENT_REF_NO,
             MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE, PAYEE_ID, PAYER_ID, IS_URGENT,
             APP_ID
        FROM APPLICATION_PAYMENT;
BEGIN
   OPEN C_APP;

   LOOP
      FETCH C_APP
      BULK COLLECT INTO PAY_TAB LIMIT 100;

      FORALL I IN 1 .. PAY_TAB.COUNT
         INSERT INTO PAYMENT
              VALUES PAY_TAB (I);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE C_APP;

   COMMIT;
END;
```

am selecting values from application_payment table  and inserting into payment table. but its taking more time and loop running without end. Help me in this am having only 78000 record in application_payment table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use select insert instead of looping

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT
 SELECT SEQ_PAYMENT.NEXTVAL PAYMENT_ID, PAYMENT_TYPE_ID, AMOUNT,
             PAYMENT_DATE, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, PAYMENT_REF_NO,
             MODIFIED_BY, MODIFIED_DATE, PAYEE_ID, PAYER_ID, IS_URGENT,
             APP_ID
        FROM APPLICATION_PAYMENT;
```